# Xcode helper "swift" consuming a lot of memory

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina, activity-monitor

On MacOS Catalina, I run Xcode 11.2 (or 11.2.1 GM). From time to time, a process called "swift" appear in Activity Monitor consuming a lot of memory, which is way more than my MacBook Pro 15' 2019 can handle it. The battery is draining very fast and the fans of the laptop are going crazy.

Can anybody can help me, or explain me if this is normal or not?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Did you inspect the process to see what it does, what files it has open?

Comment: Found the same behavior without any solution yet - https://superuser.com/questions/1494785/huge-process-called-swift-in-the-activity-monitor-appears-after-installing-xc